# Text on some activities under the title of the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-toolbar, layout-inflater

*Hello*,I would like to place the same text under the title of the app(at the top of the layout), at some of the activities of my app without affecting the other object of the layout.

- Something like a toolbar but only with text.
- Something like this
  [but not a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe5GF.png)

But i want this text only to appears whenever something is `true` and not on all the `activities`.
Any suggestions on how do i do this ? How can i implement this?

P.S. i am new to android.

Comment: you need something similar to secondary text concept along with main title?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setSubtitle()` method on your `toolbar` object. For customization you can use `setSubtitleTextAppearance (Context context, int resId)`

but documentation says -

> A title and subtitle. The title should be a signpost for the Toolbar's
>   current position in the navigation hierarchy and the content contained
>   there. The subtitle, if present should indicate any extended
>   information about the current content. If an app uses a logo image it
>   should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.

documentation link -
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setSubtitle(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

This question has already an answer. I have read it some days before. I think you should try with some different keywords like changing the title of toolbar programatically.
Here is the solution ---

```
   mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
   setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
```

once you have set an ActionBar you can change the title bar whenever you want using setTitle Method.

```
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i cannot seem to find something similar to that i want. I want this to be like a warning message when the device has no internet.

Comment: I updated the answer with solution now what you need to do is to check whether your internet connection is on or off and change the title of action bar accordingly. Using the above lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Snackbar](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)